# LAMP v/s WAMP in PHP

Tags: php

I have a small server problem when working with LAMPP and WAMP server in PHP.I am using LAMPP server for local development and I need to host in WAMP server.When try to read an image from a dynamic created pdf file in LAMPP, it is working perfectly but, the same one not compact able with WAMP server.What will be the problem?Any additional feature need to configure in WAMP.Please help me to go forward.Please........

Comment: What errors are you getting? We need more information in order to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are manipulating image(s) dynamically, you need to have the GD library enabled which can be done through php.ini file. Also your title says LAMP vs WAMP, to clarify the things LAMP stands for Lynix Apache MySQL PHP, a solutoin packed in the WAMP server.

Comment: Thank you for spending your valuable time for me.